# Haskell: show and pretty-print instance

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I started Intelligent System studies at a university and our first language is Haskell. I must admit that I am not really familiar with it so far. Part of this week's task is to develop an algebraic datatype `Expr a` which represents the basic arithmetic operations `(+,-,*,/)`.

The solution IMO should be:

```
module Expression where

data Expr a
  = Number a
  | Var
  | Sum (Expr a) (Expr a)
  | Prod (Expr a) (Expr a)
  | Div (Expr a) (Expr a)
  | Pot (Expr a) a
  deriving (Show)
```

Okay so far. The task is to implement a pretty-instance for our function now. i.e.:

from

`Plus (Pot (Var 2)) (Num 3)`

to

`x^2 + 3`

So, I had no idea what "pretty" means. After searching the internet I found out that "pretty" only means to rewrite the output in a human readable form. Is this correct? If it is, what does it mean to my function? Do I have to replace the `show` function with a `pretty` function? I don't really know where to start.

I read several similar questions here but didn't get the point there. I would really be happy if someone could give me some hints, advice, solutions or whatever!

Comment: If you're unsure about the specification of the task, you should ask your professor to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's what pretty print means.

Basically, you just need a function that converts an `Expr a` into a `String`:

```
myPrettyPrint :: Expr a -> String
```

Call it whatever you want, and don't try to replace `show`.

In order to implement this function, you'll probably want to learn about **pattern matching**.

Comment: Why not declare Show classtype for the Expr? just curious?

Comment: @RomanGonzalez: `Show` is meant as a form of lightweight serialization. It's not meant for pretty-printing, although people often abuse it that way. In particular, if a `Read` instance is also defined, one should be able to expect that `read . show` is the identity function.

Comment: @hammar: Uhmm interesting, Why isn't there a PrettyShow classtype on Prelude so that people think about this a bit more? I've been overloading Show classtype all along for Pretty printing because I didn't know any better...

Comment: @RomanGonzalez: There are several pretty-printing packages on Hackage you can write instances for. I don't think there needs to be one in the Prelude.

Comment: @hammar: it is not meant for pretty-printing, but it certainly _is_ meant for offering a format that's not harder to comprehend than necessary. `read . show` should definitely be the identity, but that's not such a severe restriction – in fact you could often define proper pretty-printing/reading functions to also behave this way. — What `show` does not offer, and IMO you should not try to make it so, is _type_ unambiguity. So, just like `"3"` is the result of both `show(3::Int)` and `show(3::Integer)`, the result of `show $ Sum x y` shouldn't need include the _name_ of the `Sum` constructor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I can agree with that to an extent, as long as you  follow the rule that `show` should be valid Haskell syntax. This is necessary for instances to cooperate properly with those of container types. For example, a `Show` instance should not return `"]foo["`, since that would break if you were to put it in a list. This does not mean that it must correspond to the compiler-derived instance. For example, the `Show` instance for `Data.Set` returns `"fromList [...]"` so that it doesn't expose the implementation-specific tree structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint Matt. The lack of knowledge about pattern matching was the problem. Function works now, wasn't even as hard as i thought before!

Answer (score 1):

I'd just implement `show` accordingly (instead of deriving from it), which can be done quite easily at least if you don't mind it to include unnecessary parentheses:

```
instance (show a) => show (Expr a) where
  show (Number x) = show x
  -- ...
  show (Prod x y) = "("++show x++")*("++show y++")"
  -- ...
```

This can be done better and more efficient, but perhaps this solution is sufficient for you.

---

It was said in comments above that `show` should be a lightwight means of serialization and should in particular fulfill `(read . show) x = x`. I agree, and it means that you should, for instance, not do any actual prettyprint stuff (like outputting to LaTeX, which would certainly be a nice way of outputting such data). It does, IMO, *not* mean that `show` should always behave like the derived instance, not if this output is unratifiably less readable, longer, and/or less clear if watched without the haskell code as context.

---

Another point hammar made in the comments above: the output of `show` should be valid haskell code. To make my solution conform to that you need to make `Expr` an instance of `Num` and either `Fractional` or `Integral`.