# Is it possible to catch this mistake using the type system, or a different design?

Tags: haskell

I was working on a small refactoring which involved converting a part of a data type from an `Int` type into a newtype wrapper. Before:

```
data Account = Account {
  accountId :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)
```

After:

```
newtype AccountId = AccountId Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data Account = Account {
  accountId :: AccountId
} deriving (Eq, Show)
```

In another part of the program I'm passing `accountId` into a function from a third-party library for the purpose of filtering the results it returns. However the filters expect `Text` input, and to convert `accountId` into that I used the following:

```
Text.pack $ show $ accountId someAccount
```

This resulted in wrong results being returned at runtime after the refactoring due to difference in `Show` instances (`"123"` vs `"AccountId 123"`).

Is there a way, either utilising the type system or a different way to convert into `Text`, that would catch this at compile time? One solution that comes to mind would be defining a helper function that takes the result of `accountId someAccount` and converts that into `Text` but perhaps there is a different/better option/pattern I'm not aware of.

Comment: By defining the automatically defined `Show` and `Read` instances, you technically break the abstraction completely - this is what you are observing. If you expose a `Show` instance, it should be e.g. `show (AccountId x) = show x`. Note that `Eq` and `Ord` don't really have such problems.

Comment: It is better not to rely on `show` to provide on its own the string representation specified by your requirements. Define a special-purpose `AccountId -> Text` function instead. See also: [*Haskell: show and pretty-print instance*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8217511/2751851).

Comment: The type system *did* prevent this mistake until you circumvented it by converting your value into a string.

Comment: Or until you instanciated Show.

Comment: If the third-party library relies on the supplied text to contain bare numbers, then its interface is wrong – why doesn't it accept numbers directly?

Comment: @user2297560 Could you clarify how this was prevented by the type system and how did I circumvent it? I may be misunderstanding what you are saying but in this instance I have little choice in interacting with a third-party API which expects string inputs.

Comment: @leftaroundabout third-party library talks to a third-party API that can filter on user-defined tags which don't have any types associated with them :-(  A tag called `accountId` can be added but no type can be specified, hence the strings.. Not a fault of the library.

Comment: Then why is there a problem? If the library only _filters_ on those tags then again it shouldn't matter whether you have the text `"AccountId 123"` or only `"123"`, as long as it's consistent (like the `Show` instance is).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm sorry but I'm not sure I follow - how could filtering by different values yield the same results? What am I missing?

Comment: You don't filter by different values. You either filter only values starting with `"AccountId"`, or only values containing just a number. If the library doesn't care what those strings contain, this shouldn't matter, it just needs to be done consistently throughout the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show is a general purpose debugging tool and is not intended for display purposes. (Its intended use case is specifically to produce a *readable* (as in `read` and `Read`) string version of your data.) Because it is general purpose, `show` does not sufficiently restrict the types on which it operates to be safe for *your* use case. You can, instead, write display functions that are specific to the types you want to display:

```
displayInt :: Int -> Text
displayInt = T.pack . show

displayAccountId :: AccountId -> Text
displayAccountId (AccountId x) = displayInt x

displayAccount :: Account -> Text
displayAccount = displayAccountId . accountId
```

This guarantees that an account can only be displayed as the int representation of its id. Of course, this implementation is highly coupled to the implementation of `Account` and `AccountId`. To reduce this coupling, a typeclass can be added:

```
class Display a where
    display :: a -> Text

instance Display Int where
    display = T.pack . show

instance Display AccountId where
    display (AccountId x) = display x

instance Display Account where
    display = display . accountId
```

This maintains the type safety (you can't accidentally `show` the wrong thing any more) while solving—to some extent—this particular instance of the expression problem.

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't adding a typeclass like `Display` open up the same way for making errors as `Show` by possibly bringing a different instance in scope? And wouldn't be this tight coupling beneficial if I want to talk specifically about accounts and their id's? In any case thank you for the answer and your help :).

Comment: Yes, but it is your typeclass and you are in control of the instances. I mentioned the tight coupling to an implementation because your original concern was being able to change your implementation. If you want tight coupling, you can have it.

Comment: Thanks again, Rein. I'm not quite sure how I could re-use this typeclass - even being in control I could only introduce the instances you listed, otherwise I would risk mixing in a different type that can be converted to `Text`, so it wouldn't be much different from the monomorphic functions?